# Как запустить из кода команду?

Tags: android, shell, java

Как запустить из java-кода команду на Андроиде?

```
cat /proc/kmsg > /mnt/sdcard/klog.log
```

Имеется ввиду, как должна выглядеть строчка `Runtime.getRuntime.exec()`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Дело в том, что перенаплавление нельзя выполнить. Можно выполнить команду с аргументами. Стало быть, надо выполнять нечто вроде такого

```
Runtime.getRuntime().exec("/bin/sh -c 'cat /proc/kmsg > /mnt/sdcard/klog.log'");
```

**UPD**

Похоже, я тоже немного облажался. У exec есть некая проблема с выполнением команд с пробелами в аргументах, так что код выше не будет работать. У меня сработал следующий:

```
ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder("/bin/sh", "-c", "cat /proc/kmsg > ~/kmem");
pb.start().waitFor();
```

Comment: Ok. Завтра попробую,отпишусь.

Comment: Файл создается, но туда ничего не пишется ((
<code>new ProcessBuilder("/system/bin/sh","-c","cat /proc/kmsg > /mnt/sdcard/klog.log).start()</code>

Comment: waitFor? А ещё может быть permission denied. На вашем месте я бы сделал mergeErrorStream и прочёл бы вывод процесса и вывел его куда-нибудь на экран. Наверняка вы увидите что-нибудь интересное.

Comment: В общем, спасибо за помощь, закрываю тему

Comment: Да, решил проблему путем написания нативного сервиса с сокетом, с рутовыми правами, только так получилось.

Comment: Звучит довольно.. безумно.. вероятно всё дело в permission denied

Answer (score 1):

`Runtime.getRuntime().exec("cat /proc/kmsg > /mnt/sdcard/klog.log")`

Но, скорее всего, это нельзя будет сделать без root привилегий.

Comment: root есть. Такое пробовал, не канает.<br>
Или есть другтие пути получения потока с логами ядра?

Comment: А что не работает? Исключение какое-нибудь или еще что?

Comment: файла нет.
Проверил через logcat -f /mnt/sdcard/logcat.log - файл есть.

Comment: Ясное дело это не сработает. root тут вообще ни при чём.