# Есть ли аналог Subprocess модуля в Руби и Яве как в Питоне?

Tags: java, ruby

Есть ли аналог Subprocess модуля в Руби и Яве как в Питоне? Как вызывать программное обеспечение и инcтрументы командой строки и биоинформатические средства из Руби и Явы, нужны примеры кода.

Comment: В яве: http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/43555/ , http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/455578/

Answer (score 4):

Простые способы описаны на [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6338908/322020).

Перевод:

- [`system`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core/Kernel.html#method-i-system) отдает команде рубишный STDIN, STDOUT, STDERR и возвращает `true`, `false` или `nil`. Использование этого метода также кладет в глобальную переменную `$?` экземпляр [`Process::Status`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core/Process/Status.html).
- Вызов команды, обрамленной в [`` ` ` ``](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core/Kernel.html#method-i-60) возвращает то, что вызыванная команда напечатала, и тоже устанавливает значение `$?`.
- `%x()` -- синтаксический сахар для `` ` ` ``, в котором экранирование работает немного иначе.
- Вызов [`exec`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core/Kernel.html#method-i-exec) гасит Ruby-процесс и отдает управление консолью новому процессу.

---

А здесь есть способы более гибкие и замороченные:
https://devver.wordpress.com/2009/06/30/a-dozen-or-so-ways-to-start-sub-processes-in-ruby-part-1/
https://devver.wordpress.com/2009/07/13/a-dozen-or-so-ways-to-start-sub-processes-in-ruby-part-2/
https://devver.wordpress.com/2009/10/12/ruby-subprocesses-part_3/