# Можно ли открыть дисковод или внешнюю программу через Ruby

Tags: ruby

Недавно я начал увлекаться языком программирования Ruby (так как он есть и в RPG Maker VX Ace версией 1.9.2) и есть множество вопросов.
Можно ли запустить/выполнить внешнюю программу или открыть дисковод. 
Меня это заинтересовало из-за инди-хоррор игр на Game Maker (знаю что у GM другой язык программирования).

Буду рад если как-нибудь, да поможете.

Если не сложно напишите пример кода, или ссылку на объяснение подобной темы.

Answer (score 1):

Да вы можете запустить внешнюю программу в обратных кавычках. Скорее всего с дисководом вам придется работать именно через какую-то внешнюю программу (боюсь платформозависимую).

```
`/path/to/external_program`
```

Comment: Попробовал я использовать эти кавычки.
Мне выдало это:

`Invalid escape character syntax`
`L:\Games\MLFP (New)\game.exe`

Comment: @ZEkA10000 В Windows придется экранировать слеш \, спасибо, разработчикам Windows за разумный выбор разделителя в путях к файлам - 30 лет скоро этой проблеме.

Answer (score 1):

Способы запуска "других программ" перечислены в ответе на другой вопрос: [Есть ли аналог Subprocess модуля в Руби и Яве как в Питоне?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/474643/178236)

Про CD-ROM вижу решение 2007 года на Win32OLE: http://rubyonwindows.blogspot.ru/2007/05/automating-windows-shell-with-ruby.html -- в принципе, должно работать и на современном Ruby и Win7.
Но есть способ и через программу-посредника MS PsExec: https://community.spiceworks.com/topic/34382-how-to-open-a-cd-drive-door-remotely

Comment: Win32ole для версии Ruby 1.9.3 и выше а у меня 1.9.2.

Comment: @ZEkA10000, точно? 1) http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-1.9.2/libdoc/win32ole/rdoc/WIN32OLE.html 2) http://apidock.com/ruby/v1_9_2_180/WIN32OLE

Answer (score 0):

Среди всех способов этот мне кажется самым удобным, если коротко:

```
IO.popen(command)
```

А для себя я написал вот такую функцию:

```
require 'colored'

# запуск внешней команды с сохранением вывода 
# если в выводе попадется true_pattern, то возращаем его индекс
def sysrun(command, true_patterns, debug)

    # запустить и считать вывод
    $lines = IO.popen(command + " 2>&1").readlines.join.split("\n")

    # если включен режим дебага, то вывести все на экран
    if debug
        puts # декоративный отступ 
        puts "\t" + "command: ".bold.black + command.to_s.green
        puts "\t" + "true patterns: ".bold.black + true_patterns.to_s.yellow
        $lines.each { |line| puts "\t" + line.to_s.cyan }
    end

    # в случае если есть пустой паттерн соответствия, но также пустой вывод - возвращаем тру
    true_patterns.each { |pattern| return 0 if (pattern.empty? && $lines.empty?) }
    true_patterns.delete("") # удаляем пустые паттерны, чтобы следующая проверка не заглючила

    # пройтись по строкам и паттернам
    $lines.each do |line| 
        true_patterns.each_with_index { |pattern, indx| return indx if (line.match pattern) }
    end

    return false
end
```

Вызов:

```
sysrun("dir", ["Volume"], true)
```