# Какая команда выполнения .exe файла на ruby

Tags: ruby

В основном находил работу с .txt файлами через File.open(), но необходим именно запуск приложения с выполнением его стандартного действия (например вызов через окно cmd c:\users\admin\desktop\programs.exe).

Comment: в большинстве языков такая функция называется system или для некоторых случаев функции группы exec. Судя по гуглу в руби функции называются так же

Comment: дубликат https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/474643/178236

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Аналогом использования в окне cmd `C:/Users/Admin/File.txt`, в коде ruby будет `system "start С:/Users/Admin/File.txt"`.